# How to compare groups using a t.test in `vtable::sumtable`?

Tags: r, vtable, hypothesis-test

I have a simple question. I'd like like to use the `group.test` argument to conduct a t.test instead of an f.test between the two groups. I see from the help documents that this should be related to the `independence.test` function but I am not quite exactly sure what to do.

```r
vtable::sumtable(data = mtcars, 
               vars = "mpg",
               group = "am", 
               out = "return",
               group.test = T)
#>   Variable  N Mean  SD  N Mean  SD       Test
#> 1       am  0           1                    
#> 2      mpg 19   17 3.8 13   24 6.2 F=16.86***
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for the slow reply; been a moment since I searched vtable.

As per the docs, as you noticed, doing a custom `group.test` requires that you write a function suitable to be passed to `independence.test`. This means that it returns a list with (1) the name of the test statistic, (2) the statistic, and (3) the p-value. So to do a t-test you'll have to write a function that does that, and then pass it to `group.test` as an option for `numeric.test` (or similarly if you want to write a function for `factor.test`)

```r
library(vtable)

data(mtcars)

custom_t = function(x, y, w = NULL) {
  t_test_result = t.test(y~x)
  stat = unname(t_test_result$statistic)
  pval = t_test_result$p.value
  return(list('t',stat,pval))
}

sumtable(mtcars, 
         vars = 'mpg',
         group = 'am',
         group.test = list('numeric.test' = custom_t))
```

**Edit:** in vtable version 1.4.5, which is now on CRAN, this is included in the package, and you can get it using `group.test = list('numeric.test' = vtable:::groupt.it)`